# Hide execution time of Jupyter cells in PyCharm 2023

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

Does anyone know how to hide the execution duration and datetime in this new version of PyCharm?

it's such a pain. I guess was introduced [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-jupyter-notebook-cells.html#run-code-cells).

[image]